# Why does NetBeans say inherited margin is invalid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, netbeans

I'm overriding a Bootstrap style for desktop, but then want the default applied for mobiles.

I could wrap the desktop in a media query, but I'd rather have a smaller mobile query to default. However, NetBeans is saying that this is invalid:

```
.reader-profile .description {margin-bottom:inherit;font-size:inherit;}
```

Because of the inherit value on margin-bottom. However, according to W3 Schools, this is a correct property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-bottom.asp

Who or what is correct?

Comment: you should trust the w3c specs: [margin-bottom](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-bottom) which state it is valid

Comment: or the updated version: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#margin-properties

Answer (score 0):

According to the w3c site [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-bottom) it is valid.

If you highlight `margin-bottom` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> you will see the exact same info as on w3.org.
Could be that netbeans is simply having a little bug in its highlighting of `unexpected characters`